# My website's subpage links giving 404 error when using online hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

It is working in localhost no problem,
but in hosting, website subpages links is not working

I don't understand where is the problem ?

I use codeingiter framework

website link : http://142.93.173.123

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: check if your server was running php using FastCGI. Change config.php to

`$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";`

Comment: @Vishwa  same my config.php and php is working

Comment: Is the base url right?

Comment: @DavideVisentin $config['base_url'] = '/'; and 

under the files  /var/www/html/

Comment: Try configuring it with `http://142.93.173.123/`